# lightning:inputField won't save null value into numeric field

Tags: lightning, inputfield, lightning-recordeditform

I use lightning:inputField for a numeric field inside the lightning:recordEditForm.  When a user tries to delete a number from that field, it shows a validation error "**cannot be parsed as a number, Value: null, Runtime class: java.lang.String**" In other words, once a number is there, you cannot replace it with a null value.

This behavior seems like a bug to me because it requires a non-null value in every numeric and/or currency field. Does anyone else observe this?

Comment: One work around could be for this issue is to assign 0 default value to integer field.

Comment: Sadly for our business use case, sometimes a 0 value in a numeric field doesn't make sense.  Users would like the ability to leave a field blank until they know what that field value should be.